# how to split this string in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I have following 3 `countryList`

```
  Korea, Republic of
  Iran, Islamic Republic of,
  Virgin Islands, U.S.
```

I am sending it through `$.ajax()` method as

```
countryList: "Korea, Republic of,Iran, Islamic Republic of,Virgin Islands, U.S."
```

and in my servlet I have code..

```
       if(request.getParameterMap().containsKey("countryList")){
                 String countryList = request.getParameter("countryList");
                 String [] countries = splitCountries(countryList);
                 for(int i = 0;i < countries.length;i++){
                     String currentCountry = countries[i];
                     dao.addCountry(username, currentCountry);
                 }
            }


     public String[] splitCountries(final String Countries)
     {
       return Countries.split(",");
     }
```

i want whole 3 country name as result but its not giving ?

Comment: Why do you think it's not giving?

Comment: are you sure that countryList is being sent to servlet?

Comment: because he has too much ",". He needs to separate countries list with other symbol, for example with ";".

Comment: because that extra comma inside indivisual countryname.

Comment: Always name your variables with a lowercase character first.

Comment: yes i am sending countryList to servlet using  var countries = $(".country").val();
                    if(countries!=null){
                     params['countryList'] = countries.join();
                    }

Comment: Why don't you send a JSON array, instead of sending a comma-separated list of values containing commas? The parsing would be much easier, because already implemented by the JSON parser.

Comment: @JB Nizet you mean like send conutryList like params['countryList'] = JSON.stringify(countries); ?

Answer (score 0):

First, You have putted one comma yourself too much in the string ;)

```
Korea, Republic of
Iran, Islamic Republic of ,  <-- the comma at the end  
Virgin Islands, U.S.
```

Second, if this is the String you get in the Servlet for param "countryList":

> countryList: "Korea, Republic of,Iran, Islamic Republic of,Virgin
>   Islands, U.S."

This means that the string got messed up already earlier, probably in the AJAX call. This string has already added somehow unwanted comma's.

Can you show your AJAX method? Especially the part where it concats the 3 'rows' to 1 string.

Comment: var countries = $(".country").val(); if(countries!=null){ params['countryList'] = countries.join(); }

Comment: try to change that a bit to:
var countries = $(".country").val(); if(countries!=null){ params['countryList'] = countries.join(' ');      <-- added a space as param to the join function